# Why do many on-line tools that can work with Dropbox or Google drive have no support for MS One drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, markdown, onedrive, dropbox-api

While looking for a decent in-browser Markdown editor that could be connected to MS One drive, I noticed an interesting thing. A few fairly popular editors have possibility to work with files stored on either Dropbox or on Google drive, but not on MS One drive. Examples: [Writebox](https://write-box.appspot.com/), [Stackedit](https://stackedit.io/), [Dillinger](https://dillinger.io/). The last one claims to have support for One drive amongst other drives but it does not work, I checked it (later I discovered [this non-closed ticket](https://github.com/joemccann/dillinger/issues/718) that had been raised... five years ago!).

Why is this? What is so special about One drive API compare to those of others. Clearly, the APIs are different, but was MS One drive API designed in such a way to make it difficult for indie developer software to connect to One drive? If so, which purpose does this unnatural limitation serve?

Comment: probably because the kind of people that write markdown (and develop markdown editors) are not the kind of people invested in the MS ecosystem? if you're in the MS ecosystem, usually you just use Word?
that being said, this question is probably off-topic for stackoverflow...

Comment: @mb21 The question is not why people have no wish to create programs capable of interacting with MS ecosystem constituents (I agree it would be an improper question for SE). But I take it for granted that developers do want their software being used, so it is only logical to offer wider selection of possibilities whether they like MS or not. Rather I wonder if there are any objective reasons why the developers avoid doing this: technical reasons (API is too complicated), legal reasons (restrictive licencing), reasons related to efforts (need to modify the code too often due to changes in API).

Comment: every additional API is effort. All three projects you mentioned are volunteer-drive, just like my panwriter.com – and I can tell you that while I thought about adding Dropbox or Google Drive sync, it never even occured to me to add MS One. Simply because I know nobody that's using it, and because I assumed (perhaps wrongly) that people that use MS stuff wouldn't be interested in a markdown editor.

Comment: @mb21 Well, you are right. Every one I know (including myself) prefers to use either Dropbox or Google drive, but sometimes you just do not have choice. Connecting to any of these two is nixed on the corporate machine I am working with. They have no objections to storing notes in MS One drive as soon as the Markdown editor is an in-browser one, though (strangely enough, they are fine with using personal MS account rather than the corporate one). By the way if you happen to know such an editor (anything would be better for storing collection of notes than MS Word, I presume), please tip me off.

Comment: Are GitHub gists allowed? if so, try https://hackmd.io/features#Save-a-Note

Comment: @mb21 No, unfortunately not. It is either MS One drive or get lost.

Comment: Sorry for so many repetitions (I have deleted them). It is a SE failure, rather than my black humour.